# What does $q\%p$ mean

Tags: notation

Sorry for such a simple question.

In notes on quadratic reciprocity there was a phrase replace $q$ by $q$%$p$. $p$, $q$ are odd primes.

What does that mean? Thanks

Comment: Presumably $p$ and $q$ are the two primes in the statement of quadratic reciprocity. And $q\% p$ means $q\mod p$.

Comment: Please give us a little more context. It could mean something as simple as the remainder when $q$ is divided by $p$

Comment: In programming languages, $q\% p$ is the remainder of $q$ divided by $p$.  Mathematicians more commonly notate a similar operation as $q\pmod{p}$, except that $q\% p$ returns specifically an integer from $\{0,1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ whereas $q\pmod{p}$ technically returns an equivalence class $r+p\Bbb Z$.  Often $\pmod{p}$ has the same use however.

Comment: @JMoravitz Most commonly, $q\bmod p$ is an operation (the same as $q\%p$ in some programming languages) while $q\pmod {p}$ is an equivalence relation. Relevant Wikipedia links: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_relations

Comment: In a computer language like c or c++ it would be the remainder after dividing q with p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many common programming languages, such as java, c, c++, the percent sign is used as a modulo operator.  [see this page for example](http://www.javaranch.com/drive/modulo.html).  In practice, one has $q\% p =q-p\lfloor q/p\rfloor$ for $p\neq 0$ and $0$ otherwise.  In other words, the modulo operator outputs the *remainder* of the division operation $q/p$.

For examples, $23\% 5 = 3$ and $15\% 3 = 0$

While not frequently used in mathematical contexts, the notation does find its way into some papers and textbooks with the meaning described above, especially if the author is an experienced coder.  (*Feel free to edit in a citation.  I expected Knuth's art of computer programming to use this notation, but he instead uses the notation below*)

More commonly seen in mathematical contexts, is instead $q\bmod p$ or $q\pmod{p}$.

Donald Knuth defines (see section 1.2.4 of Knuth's *Art of Computer Progrmaming*) $x\bmod y$ in the same way as above: $x\bmod y = \begin{cases} 0&\text{if}~ y=0\\ x-y\lfloor x/y\rfloor&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

On the other hand, $\pmod{z}$ is used when referring to the equivalence relation:

$x\equiv y\pmod{z} \iff x\bmod z = y\bmod z \iff z\mid(x-y)~~~\textit{or z=0}$